# How to override outlook 2013 contact context menu ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook-2013

How to override outlook 2013 contact context menu ribbon through coding.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but...

I just recently started looking into doing this same thing, myself, and here's what I found. There's a pretty good article on doing this very same thing in VB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee909466%28v=office.14%29.aspx

The information there can be relatively easily adjusted to do the same thing in C#, but there are some holes. I asked a question earlier today that contains some of the missing pieces: [How can I reliably get the object of a contact context menu in an Outlook 2013 addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970060/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-object-of-a-contact-context-menu-in-an-outlook-2013-a)

Also, it will probably be useful to look at the list of Control Identifiers, which can be downloaded from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36798