# Find out which contact the user right clicked on

Tags: c#, vsto, contextmenu, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

thank you in advance for your help. I have been looking for a solution by myself for a while.

The context: I added a new context menu when the user right-clicks on a contact. Its id is `ContextMenuContactCardRecipient`.

The problem: When the user is in this context menu and clicks on my new button, I need to know which contact the user right-clicked to get to the context menu.

I could not find a way to retrieve the contact items details... Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

The answer provided here does not work for me:
[How can I reliably get the object of a contact context menu in an Outlook 2013 addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970060/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-object-of-a-contact-context-menu-in-an-outlook-2013-a/49415654?noredirect=1#comment85833033_49415654)

Thank you!

Comment: Web addin does not allow to add context menu\

Comment: It is not a web addin.

Comment: yes, you can get contact email address  in call back method. If it is oeky for you let me know. if will give code, if you need paid version trainining let me know :)

Comment: I already have one call back method on my new contextmenu item to have an action. But for this action I need the right clicked contact email address. If you can give some clues on how to do this it will be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but can be helpful for others!

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
      <contextMenus>
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuContactCardRecipient">
          <button id="myMenuBtn"
              label="get mail email"
              onAction="lookForMe"
              visible="true"/>
        </contextMenu>
      </contextMenus>
    </customUI>
```

**C#**

```
        public void lookForMe(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Office.IMsoContactCard card = control.Context as Office.IMsoContactCard;
        string email = GetSmtpAddress(card);
        if (email != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://org.ad.com/" + email);
        }
    }

    private string GetSmtpAddress(Office.IMsoContactCard card)
    {
        if (card.AddressType == Office.MsoContactCardAddressType.msoContactCardAddressTypeOutlook)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application host = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry ae = host.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(card.Address);

            if ((ae.AddressEntryUserType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry 
                || ae.AddressEntryUserType == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry))
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser ex = ae.GetExchangeUser();
                return ex.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
            else
                throw new System.Exception("unvalid address entry not found.");
        }
        else
            return card.Address;
    }
```